# Visual Odometry, Kitti Dataset

Tags: computer-vision, dataset, kitti, odometry

I am currently trying to make a stereo visual odometry using Matlab with the [KITTI dataset](http://www.cvlibs.net/download.php?file=data_odometry_gray.zip)

I know the folder '[poses.txt](http://www.cvlibs.net/download.php?file=data_odometry_poses.zip)' contains the ground truth poses (trajectory) for the
first 11 sequences. Each file xx.txt contains an N x 12 table, where N is the number of
frames of this sequence. But, what are these 12 parameters? x,y,z, row, pitch, yaw and what?

My second question is if I want to create my own dataset, how can I acquire these poses with IMU?

Comment: Notice that x, y, z it's [3], [7], [11] elements in each row of poses.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each row of the file contains the first 3 rows of a 4x4 homogeneous pose matrix flattened into one line.
It means that this matrix:

```
r11 r12 r13 tx
r21 r22 r23 ty
r31 r32 r33 tz
0   0   0   1
```

is represented in the file as a single row:
`r11 r12 r13 tx r21 r22 r23 ty r31 r32 r33 tz`
Search "4x4 homogeneous pose matrix" in Google or read this:
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MARBLE/high/pose/express.htm
or this
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82602/how-to-find-camera-position-and-rotation-from-a-4x4-matrix

Answer (score 1):

The 12 elements are flattened 3x4 matrix of which 3x3 are for rotation and 3x1 are for translation.

You can convert these into other representations like euler(roll, pitch, yaw), quaternion.